# Send Mail to a user if count of open issues greater a specific limit

Tags: youtrack

how could i create a workflow which on every change of the current issue user checks the total amount of open issues for this user and if the amount is greater then lets say 5 the user gets a mail with a little warning message?

I guess this here is close to my topic, but only close:
https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206582955-How-to-count-user-s-issues-

All our users have a mail in youtrack, the workflow should only work for one usergroup/project however.

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 2):

The [How to count user's issues?](https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206582955-How-to-count-user-s-issues-) illustrates the approach that valid for old workflow.
For the new JavaScript workflow, I suggest you use the [search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/v1-search.html#search) method for getting all open issues assigned to the required user. Then, you can use the [user.notify](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/v1-User.html#notify) method to send an email to this user. 
You can find common information about JavaScript workflow in the [JavaScript Workflow Quick Start Guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Quick-Start-Guide-Workflows-JS.html) article. I hope this helps. 
Here is an example that illustrates how to send a message with the assigned issues count to the user:

```js
var entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
var search = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/search');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  title: 'Assignee count',
  guard: function(ctx) {
    return ctx.issue.isChanged(ctx.Assignee) && ctx.issue.fields.Assignee;
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    var issue = ctx.issue;

    var user = issue.fields.Assignee;
    var query = 'for: ' + user.login + ' #Unresolved';
    var assignedToUser = search.search(issue.project, query, ctx.currentUser);

    var count = assignedToUser.size;
    var subj = 'Attention!';
    var body = 'You have ' + count + ' assigned issues';
    user.notify(subj, body);
  },
  requirements: {
    Assignee: {
      type: entities.User.fieldType
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg. Im not really good in JavaScript, but the bigger problem is - i dont really understand the workflow system with the requirements/entities and so on. Maybe you could give me some more hints on how to write it down as javascript workflow?

Comment: I have added an example that illustrates how to send a message with the assigned issues count to the user.